# Windows Universal App Threading

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-10, win-universal-app

In my Universal Windows App (Windows 10), I need to create a thread that lasts the entire time the app is running.
The UI work will execute on the UI thread while some tasks will be handled in a separate thread in a queue.
From what I understand, System.Threading is not supported in Universal apps.
I read about the Threadpool but I don't understand how it can solve my purpose.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: What kind of work do you expect to be doing in your thread?

Comment: @spender mostly data transfer via a socket - but the socket cant be disconnected

Comment: So, this leads me to believe that you're falling into an XY problem. The principles behind universal apps is to steer you away from blocking APIs. If you embrace async/await and tasks, it is possible to interact with the network over a single (non-disconnecting) socket without the need for any explicit threading, while keeping the UI fluid. The only case where additional threads *might* be required is in the case of CPU intensive work.

Comment: @spender so are you saying that I should not create a separate thread and instead create small worker tasks for each time I need to perform an operation? This would change the architecture of the app that I already have running on older platforms supporting System.Threading.

Comment: How will your app deal with Suspending and Thombstoning?

Comment: @HenkHolterman that is the only time the socket can be disconnected, it is reset and reconnected in that case

Comment: @HenkHolterman the app needs to be in continuous communication with ther server

Answer (score 0):

For more details about threading visit [this](http://codesamplez.com/programming/multithreaded-programming-c-sharp) page.
ThreadPool Sample:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new Program().testThread1);
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new Program().testThread2);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public void testThread1(Object threadContext)
        {
            //executing in thread
            int count = 0;
            while (count++ < 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thread 1 Executed "+count+" times");
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }

        public void testThread2(Object threadContext)
        {
            //executing in thread
            int count = 0;
            while (count++ < 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thread 2 Executed " + count + " times");
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
    }
```